# Cron Job to run a .php file fails

Tags: php, cron

I have an issue. Raspberry Pi with Raspberry Pi OS Lite. I have a .php file located in /var/www/html/bloomsky.php

This .php file just calls for a new image to be downloaded from AmazonAWS servers on a 1 minute interval (testing at 1 minute , but will bump to 5 or so in the future) When I access the website and point it directly at the bloomsky.php file then the PHP file does work to download an updated image and overwrite the image that was present in /var/www./html/image.jpg

When I check the time stamp of the image.jpg file it shows the current time that the bloomsky.php file reached out and grabbed a new one and overwrote it.

So the PHP file is working as intended.
So I created a cron job to run that bloomsky.php file on a regular consistent basis.
Used `Crontab -e` to create the entry
Here is the entire file

```html
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').
#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).

# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command
 * * * * * root /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/bloomsky.php
```

I have also tried

```
 * * * * * root /var/www/html/bloomsky.php
```

I have also rebooted after saving these changes.

If the Cron job was working correctly every minute it would launch the `Bloomsky.php` file and download and overwrite the `image.jpg` file thereby updating its timestamp details.

Thats not happening. I also made a copy of the `Bloomsky.php` file and placed it in my home directory.

Comment: whats the dot in /var/www./html/image.jpg, does this come from your script? also tail -f /var/log/syslog to get a sense if its running

Comment: The per-user crontabs that you edit with `crontab -e` do not have the username before the command. That's only used in `/etc/crontab`.

Comment: So get rid of the word `root` before `/usr/bin/php`

Comment: That dot (.) was a typo in the post by me. It has no significance as it does not exist . Its actually /var/www/html/image.jpg

Comment: I do not understand the tail -f comment @Sam Washington

Comment: Changed my cron file to remove the root username as instructed 
# m h  dom mon dow   command
 * * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/bloomsky.php
Still not updating.

Comment: I just SSH into the /var/www/html directory and refresh the files there to see if the image.jpg has an updated time stamp. It does not. I just keep refreshing the file list and no change.

Comment: Add `2>~/error.txt` to the end of the command line. Then check that file to see if there are any error messages.

Comment: Barmar - Please explain

Comment: What @Barmar meant is modify your cron from 

* * * * * /var/www/html/bloomsky.php

to

* * * * * /var/www/html/bloomsky.php 2>~/error.txt

Comment: another option is that at your terminal after ssh, just run /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/bloomsky.php and see what's the output

Comment: I ran the above command and here is the output root@WebServerPi:~#  /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/bloomsky.php
Download of http://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/bskyimgs/gqBxp6apnJSnnZm2qJ1mqZutm                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             root@WebServerPi:~#

Comment: @ZeffTang That's not always helpful -- a common question is "Why does this work in the terminal but fail in cron?"

Comment: The php script appears to work and download the updated image which has a long name of characters that is ever changing. Although when I access the bloomsky.php file when accessing it using a web browser the message presented on the web page is slightly different. This is what it reads Download of http://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/bskyimgs/gqBxp6apnJSnnZm2qJ1mqZutmpGpmpU=.jpg done!

Comment: Here is the contents of my Crontab file after making the changes that Barmar indicated  * * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/bloomsky.php 2>~/error.txt

Comment: You can actually click on that link above and it will show the image presented from the Bloomsky camera

Comment: It seems like when I manually run the command from the terminal it cuts off the trailing .jpg specifier and the Done! message.

Comment: Here is a link to an image of the differences I see between terminal and web browser https://www.dropbox.com/s/8xvdwc6f5yjm2k4/Term_HTTP.jpg?dl=0

Comment: I went looking for the error.txt file and found it under /root  To my surprise I also found the image.jpg file that WAS being updated every minute as the Cron Job appears to be running , but placing the file in /root rather than where I would like it at /var/www/html    How can I have it placed in the directory above?

Comment: I would like the updated image.jpg to be in /var/www/html and not /root

Comment: Solved it by adding a fully qualified path within the bloomsky.php to indicate the entire path to save the file such as $image = '/var/www/html/image.jpg';     Thanks you for all the willingness to help